Default server being selected even after specifying environment in profiles in mvn clean test -Pqa
I am running selenium-testNG scripts using below command so that I can run it in a particular server that I choose to
mvn clean test -Pqa

But the test script is running in the default server url instead
pom.xml:
 <profiles>
        <!-- Profile for QA environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <server.url>"https://my_qa_url.com/"</server.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile for Production environment -->
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <server.url>"https://my_prod_url/"</server.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

java class:
public static final String REGRESSION_SERVER = System.getProperty("server.url","https://my_default_url.com/");

Command used:
 mvn clean test -Pqa 

Expectation:
Tests run in the server specified in the profileID qa , ie, https://my_qa_url.com/
Actual:
Tests ran in default url, ie, https://my_default_url.com/
Please provide some pointers to resolve

POM properties are NOT System properties... System properties are things like mvn -Dsystem.property=value ... ...

How can this be resolved ?

I was able to resolve this by adding below line to pom.xml:  ${server}
